# reinterpret_cast to QObject's subling

Tags: c++, qobject, reinterpret-cast

I've got some kind of object factory (template based), that works pretty good for my purposes. But now I've tried to work with class, that derives from both QObject and pure abstract class (interface) and I've got strange run-time errors.

Here the simple picture of this class (Derived)

```
class Interface  {
public:
    Interface(){}
    virtual ~Interface(){}    
    virtual int getResult() = 0;
};

class Derived : public QObject, public Interface {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Derived(QObject *parent = 0);        
    int getResult();        
};
```

and its implementation in derived.cpp:

```
#include "derived.h"    
Derived::Derived(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent) {
}    
int Derived::getResult() {
    return 55;
}
```

When I try to cast void pointer to the Interface, I'll get unexpected (for me) behavior, it can be or runtime error, or other method call (it depends of classes' size).

```
#include "derived.h"    
void * create() {
    return new Derived();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Interface * interface = reinterpret_cast<Interface *>(create());    
    int res = interface->getResult(); // Run-time error, or other method is called here
    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain me why I cannot cast void pointer to interface? And is there any workaround?

Thanks for your responses

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`? have you tried `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: I cannot use `dynamic_cast` to `void*`, because there aren't RTTI in `void*`. (Because of templates, my factory always returns `void*` and than casts it to the required template type, so I have to work with `void*` - there are tons of legacy code with such approach.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [reinterpret\_cast, casting to brother class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975497/reinterpret-cast-casting-to-brother-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinterpreting a pointer to a derived class as a pointer to a base class gives undefined behaviour. This is highlighted by multiple inheritance: since there is more than one base class, and the two base subobjects must have different addresses, they can't *both* have the same address as the derived object. So the pointer returned by your `create` function points to a `Derived`, but not necessarily to the `Interface` subobject. It could point to `QObject` subobject, or to neither.

The best option is to return `Derived*` or `Interface*` from your function; if it must be `void*` for some reason, then the only well-defined cast you can make is back to `Derived*`, which can then be converted to `Interface*` using standard conversions.

By using `void*` you have thrown away all static and dynamic knowledge of the type; the only way to restore that information is to cast back to the correct type.

Comment: OK, I've got it. Its my fault when I tried to use brutal cast from `void*` with multiple inheritance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `reinterpret_cast` with multiple inheritance will likely cause all kinds of problems. In your case, the `void*` will probably point to the `QObject` part of the `Derived`, not the `Interface` part.

It would probably work better with a `dynamic_cast`, which can adjust the pointer to point to the correct subobject of the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general, the need for these types of casts are a sign of bad design. In your specific case, your factory function needs to return an `Interface*`. `void*` in C++ where no C interfacing is involved is just unnecessary and bad.

Apart from all this, factory functions are something of a Java thing, and only required when applying strict design methodology, which often adds more fluff than contributing to clean and bug-free code.

If that doesn't cut it, you'll want [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). In Qt for QObjects, you can see if [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#qobject_cast) has any merit in your situation.